# Android in Tablayout, ViewPager addad again data from JSON to ListView

Tags: android, json, listview, android-fragments

I have four fragment in tablayout with listview each and I fill listview from JSON. So when I slide fragment, for example, see first fragment further see other fragment and when I again return to first fragment I found that the data doubled(or again loaded and add down old listview data).It happens to every fragment. How to make that data is not doubled. I've been doing this program for http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

This is Fragment1.
    public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

```
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";
public static String LOG_TAG = "my_log";

ListView list;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
LazyAdapter adapter;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag, container, false);
    ParseTask pt = new ParseTask();
    pt.execute();
    Activity ac = new Activity();

    list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(getActivity(), songsList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);


    list.setOnItemClickListener(
            new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityTwo.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );

   return rootView;
}


private class ParseTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String resultJson = "";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // получаем данные с внешнего ресурса
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://zhaksy-adam.kz/api/Requisitions/GetRequisition");

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }
            resultJson = buffer.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultJson;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
        super.onPostExecute(strJson);

        JSONObject jsonobj = null;

        try {
            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(strJson);

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                jsonobj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                String type = jsonobj.getString("type");
                if(type.equals("Нужен помощь")) {

                    // Adding picture url
                    String img = jsonobj.getString("Picture1");
                    if (img != null) {
                        img = "http://zhaksy-adam.kz" + img;
                        img = img.replace("~/", "/");
                        img = img.replace(" ", "%20");
                    }

                    map.put(KEY_ID, jsonobj.getString("ID"));
                    map.put(KEY_TITLE, jsonobj.getString("Title"));
                    map.put(KEY_DURATION, jsonobj.getString("Date"));
                    map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, img);

                    songsList.add(map);

                }
            }
        }catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

}

This is my adapter

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader;
MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
    TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist); // artist name
    TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.duration); // duration
    ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
    song = data.get(position);

    // Setting all values in listview
    title.setText(song.get(Fragment1.KEY_TITLE));
    artist.setText(song.get(Fragment1.KEY_ARTIST));
    duration.setText(song.get(Fragment1.KEY_DURATION));
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(Fragment1.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);
    return vi;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the content of songlist map are not cleared. So in your `onPostExecute` whenever you get the data make sure that you clear the songsList by using `songsList.clear()` method.
So the snippet of your fragment code will become as follows :

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
        super.onPostExecute(strJson);

        JSONObject jsonobj = null;

        try {
             if(songList!=null){
                songList.clear();
             }
            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(strJson);

                . . . .
                . . . .
                your code   
                    songsList.add(map);

                }
            }
        }catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

The reason for this is because songsList  is declared and initialize while its on create lifecycle of fragment, but asyntask is utilizing same instance everytime, so new data is added everytime intead of overwriting it.

Hope this helps you

Comment: If you have doubt about losing the existing data, then have a backup of data before processing the new data, once new data is processed compare new and old data and accordingly create a final list and pass to the adapter

Comment: thank you this helps me. May I ask something also, when app run first time the data in listview on first fragment absent and it showed after slide to other fragment

Comment: Your songList is initially empty, and when asyntask finishes you got the data, so when the for loop of inserting data to songList finishes, use adatper.notifyDataSetChanged() method so the listview will get refreshed data, you can use this method whenever you make changes in data of listview

Comment: One more question, in list.setOnItemClickListener() method i want to sent ID of  particular item to another activity and i have to get ID from json. How can i do it?

Comment: I think the position of item in listview is the position of data in the songList, so you get the position of item you clicked, so you can get the whole data for that clicked item from the songList, you can use songList.get(position).<KEY_ID>